# dotTrace: is there a TeamCity plugin?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, teamcity, dottrace

I'm investigating whether we can run performance testing with code check ins to `TeamCity` / `TFS`..

Does anyone know whether this is possible or not?

Comment: Good idea. If you open a youTrack issue, I'll sure as heck upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordingly to the [jetBrains dotTrace Developer Community post](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5320391;jsessionid=334501CF1A37025975133C46F67801D2):

> DotTrace 4 command line support is scheduled to dotTrace Performance
>   version 4.6 (release in September 2011)
>
> 4.6 EAP will start  earlier.

This mean that you would be able to write simple MSBuild/NAnt script which executes dotTrace from command line and then extract a results set XML file and show in TeamCity as well.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it, however TeamCity does provide the duration time for unit tests and a historical graph of those tests over time. If you use the Category attribute of your runner to group tests, you should be able to create a performance fixture that shows up in the TeamCity build output.